# I suddenly cannot connect to my EC2 instance. Why? How can I mitigate this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had a running instance, and then I became unable to connect to it via http(80) and ssh(22). I tried to reboot the instance, but nothing went up. This has happened to me twice in the past month.

Why does it happen? Can I do anything to fix and/or prevent it from happening?

If I launch a new instance in same region, and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Things to check when trying to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **Security Group:** Make sure the security group allows **inbound** access on the desired ports (eg 80, 22) for the appropriate IP address range (eg `0.0.0.0/0`). This solves the majority of problems.
- **Public IP Address:** Check that you're using the correct Public IP address for the instance. If the instance is stopped and started, it *might* receive a new Public IP address (depending on how it has been configured).
- **VPC Configuration:** Accessing an EC2 instance that is launched inside a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) requires:

  - An **Internet Gateway**
  - A **routing table** connecting the subnet to the Internet Gateway
  - **NACLs** (Network ACLS) that permit through-traffic

If you are able to launch and connect to another instance in the same subnet, then the VPC configuration would appear to be correct.

The other thing to check would be the actual **configuration of the operating system** on the instance itself. Some software may be affecting the configuration so that the web server / ssh daemon is not working correctly. Of course, that is hard to determine without connecting to the instance.

If you are launching from a standard Amazon Linux AMI, `ssh` would work correctly anytime. The web server (port 80) would require installation and configuration of software on the instance, which is your responsibility to maintain.

Comment: I thin the key word in the question is *suddenly*